# Xamarin Android - Geofence service is not working although everything is implemented

Tags: c#, xamarin, service

I am working on a Xamarin Forms project, and I am trying to implement some geofencing. It is working well, but when the app is closed, it is not doing anything. 
I am using this NuGet (https://github.com/CrossGeeks/GeofencePlugin) and different Android OS', which are Android 7, 8 and 9.
I implemented everything as said on the GitHub page, and the Android specifics in the Android project. In the console it appears that the service is started.

I did some documentation about services but from what I understand from the GitHub page you don't need to implement anything else, and the restrictions begin with Android 8, but on Android 7 it still doesn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish when the app is closed?

Comment: Trying to do an HTTP request which will send a push notification to the user.

Comment: Can you add that code to your post?